# Tolerar Errores Try Catch

Tags: c#, visual-studio, try-catch

Quisiera que mi programa continué con la ejecución cuando se produzca un error en el bloque try. Es decir, que tolere errores (no es necesario saber que hay dentro de mi bloque Try, no hace a la finalidad de mi consulta)

[image: el error]

```
         try
         {
            //Ejecución de código 
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
           //Acá el programa crashea y yo quisiera que continúe omitiendo los errores
         }
```

Comment: es que errores va a seguir emitiendo siempre, y siempre vas a atraparlos y no hacer nada con estos, sino quiere que se genere errores entonces validalo antes que se produzcas asi no necesitas ninguna try..catch

Comment: ahora esto de la emision es algo que notas porque el Visual Studio detiene la ejecucion o no tiene nada que ver, porque si elgo del debug entonces es otra cosa

Comment: Leandro, coloqué una imagen del error que deseo pasar por alto. Si no coloco nada en el catch el sistema igual se cuelga.

Comment: ¿Tu `catch` real se ve así como muestras (`catch (Exception ex)`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si dentro del catch no pones nada, el codigo seguirá, pero ten en cuenta que no es una buena practica, deberias ver porque esta fallando y a partir de esa excepcion generada actuar correctamente, sea devolviendo un error como mensaje o generando en un log un aviso al menos, un ejemplo si fuera una aplicacion de consola:

```
Console.WriteLine("Codigo antes de excepcion");

try
{               
    // fuerzo una excepcion para que se vea como la captura y luego el codigo sigue...
    throw new Exception('prueba de arrojar un error y capturarlo');
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Excepcion ocurrió: {0}", e.Message);
}

Console.WriteLine("Codigo luego de excepcion se ejecutara");
```

update:
de acuerdo a tu actualizacion lo que se ve que esta sucediendo es que luego de que utilizaras using o que realizaras object.dispose() intentas seguir utilizando un objeto que ya no se puede.... o necesitas meter el uso de ese objeto en el using o antes de que se llame a .dispose() para evitar ese error

seguramente estas queriendo utilizar luego del bloque catch el objeto que ya se ha desechado con dispose() previamente.

Comment: Fabian, he editado mi pregunta y dejo una imagen del error que quiero pasar por alto. Por otra parte si en el catch no coloco nada el sistema igual se cuelga. Me proyecto es con windows Forms

Comment: creo que deberas ver el stacktrace  o algun detalle de la excepcion arrojada para ver donde esta fallando, pues como indica la excepcion que te arroja, es una "excepcion no controlada" , o sea no esta ocurriendo dentro de un bloque try/catch, sino te dejaria continuar y no fallaria

Comment: Fabian, tenias razón cuando mencionas "no es dentro de un bloque try/catch, sino te dejaría continuar y no seria una "excepcion no controlada" " 
El error se daba en otra función fuera de mi Try Catch, por lo tanto en esa función coloqué un try catch nuevo, el sistema ya no crashea y omite el error. Muchas Gracias. Marcado como respuesta.

Comment: que bueno que hayas encontrado el problema, de todas maneras te vuelvo a recomendar no utilizar esta practica y en primera medida evitar que el codigo falle, sino el codigo no te quedará muy legible y en caso de que falle por cualquier otra cosa tu codigo, no lo detectaras pues "lo omitirá", lo que no está bueno al momento de agregar nuevo codigo.... solo una recomendacion importante.

Comment: Fabian, lo tendré en cuenta ya que es para un proyecto grande. Ya volveré a preguntar sobre como solucionar la excepción. Por el momento pondré foco en la implementación y quedará para solucionar luego de la prueba de testeo.

Answer (score 0):

Lo ideal (lo correcto) es que en cuanto detectes un error, intentes implementar código para que este nunca suceda, eso dice la teoría pero sabemos que en algunas ocasiones esto no será posible.
La ventana que nos muestras es la de Exception Helper, pero me parece extraño que te aparezca cuando tienes un código en donde manejas la excepción, lo cual me hace entender que esa excepción aparece dentro de la parte de código del catch (Exception ex), con lo cual debes tener más cuidado, pues al intentar manejar un error estás generando otro.
En el peor de los casos, si definitivamente no quieres darle tratamiento a ese error, puedes probar metiendo otro try...catch dentro del bloque catch en cuestión.

```
     try
     {
        //Ejecución de código 
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        try
        {
           // Aquí deberías meter tu código del catch para manejar el primer error.
        }
        catch (Exception ex2)
        {
           // Aquí manejas el segundo error, provocado por tu código anterior. Pero insisto, deberías revisar que no pase un segundo error, pues ya algo no anda bien en la lógica.
        }
     }
```

Comment: Quedaría mucho más claro si aportaras un código mostrando como se hace.

Comment: De acuerdo, ya modifiqué la respuesta. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

puede que te sirva esta respuesta. Si no quieres manejar el error, pero sabes que si podría fallar el código, y requieres, que aún sin cumplirse la promesa se ejecute cierto código, simplemente usa Try... finally. O sea:

```
try
{
   //Ejecución de código que puede fallar
}
finally
{
  //Código que si o si se va a ejecutar trates o no el error.
}
```

Pero para que sea un código, más limpio y trazable, deberías por lo menos agregar el catch metiendo un log o algo por el estilo, de la misma forma:

```
Try
{
   //Ejecución de código 
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   //Código que deja un log en el sistema o realiza tareas que restablezcan 
   //variables del código que falló
}
finally
{
   //Código, que si o si, se va a ejecutar trates o no el error.
}
```

Answer (score -4):

```
try
{
    //Aqui tus lineas de código que pudiesen generar una excepción o dondé crashea
}
catch(ObjectDisposeException e){
  //AQUI OMITES ESTA EXCEPCION
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   //Acá el programa omité otras excepciones
}
```

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).